# Let SWFObject update flash, but don't require it

Tags: flash, swfobject

I have a game that will work better in Flash Player 11 (with Molehill) but also works in 10.3. I'd like to get players to automatically update to 11 with express install as much as possible (after it's released, of course), but don't want to force them.

I tried this way of embedding it with SWFObject:

```
swfobject.embedSWF(
    // url
    "game.swf?version=1",
    // content to replace
    "flashContent",
    // size
    "910", "658",
    // flash version
    "11",
    // expressInstall
    "playerProductInstall.swf",
    // flashvars
    {},
    // params
    {
        wmode: "transparent",
        allowScriptAccess: "always"
    },
    // object attributes
    {},
    // callback
    function(e) {
        if (e.success) {
            console.log("SWF loaded", e);
            gameSwf = e.ref;
        } else {
            console.log("SWF not loaded", e);
        }
    }
);
```

However, that will make the game *require* 11, which means that if express install doesn't work (Linux) or is cancelled by the user, the game is not loaded, even though it would run fine.

Is there another way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Make the required version 10.3
Then write javascript to detect if the version is 11. If not, show the update link.

Better still would be to just require fp11, it will cause no harm

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Pravnav's answer, I would embed the game using 10.3, then place a small banner above the movie that says their version of Flash Player is out of date and the game performs best with FP 11+.  Make the banner clickable and use swfobject's [`swfobject.showExpressInstall`](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api#swfobject.showExpressInstall%28att,_par,_replaceElemIdStr,_callbac) method to trigger Express Install.

The tricky part is Express Install support: as you said, EI doesn't work in Linux, but it also doesn't work in Google Chrome, since Chrome uses an embedded self-updating version of FP.  Might be useful to write some sniffing JS that provides a link to Adobe.com for those browsers instead of using Express Install.

Comment: "since Chrome uses an embedded self-updating version of FP"  ...
doesn't that mean that chrome is always up to date?

Comment: It means that Google handles the update process. I haven't seen any documentation claiming that they always use the latest release, so I'm not comfortable saying Chrome is always up to date (though it might very well be).

Comment: as it turns out, if you go to the get flash page with chrome, there is no download - it tells you "chrome is automatically up to date, good job" or words to that effect.